# Unresolved external symbol error occurring only in 64-bit mode and not in 32-bit build

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I have a VC++ code (built using VS2008), which makes use of some static libraries (*.lib files linked statically during compile time).

For ease of understanding let's refer my EXE code as "AAA.EXE" & refer the lib files as "A.lib", b.lib etc...

Both the AAA.EXE code and static libraries code are built using VS2008.

**I see that my "AAA.EXE" is working fine in 32-bit version and showing the below linker errors  when AAA.EXE is built in 64-bit mode.**

I have of course rebuilt the static libraries in 64-bit mode and provided the lib path in my AAA.EXE like this :: "Project Configuration Properties corresponding to AAA.EXE -> Linker -> General/Input".

This linker error is really bothering me form a long time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Logger.lib(Loggerr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall CWTTLogger::CWTTLogger(void)" (__imp_??0CWTTLogger@@QAE@XZ)    

1>Logger.lib(Logger.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall CWTTLogger::~CWTTLogger(void)" (__imp_??1CWTTLogger@@UAE@XZ)    

1>Logger.lib(Logger.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: long __thiscall CWTTLogger::FunctionA(unsigned short *,long *)" (__imp_?FunctionA@CWTTLogger@@QAEJPAGPAJ@Z)     

1>Logger.lib(Logger.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: long __thiscall CWTTLogger::FunctionB(unsigned short *,long)" (__imp_?FunctionB@CWTTLogger@@QAEJPAGJ@Z)     

1>Logger.lib(Logger.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: long __thiscall CWTTLogger::FunctionC(unsigned short *,unsigned long,unsigned short *,long)" (__imp_?FunctionC@CWTTLogger@@QAEJPAGK0J@Z)     

1>Logger.lib(Logger.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: long __cdecl CWTTLogger::FunctionD(unsigned long,long,...)" (__imp_?FunctionD@CWTTLogger@@QAAJKJZZ)             

1>Logger.lib(Logger.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: long __thiscall CWTTLogger::FunctionE(unsigned short *,long)" (__imp_?FunctionE@CWTTLogger@@QAEJPAGJ@Z)         


1>C:\Users\User1\Documents\XYZ\Code\64bit\aaa.exe: fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

Also to add ::

I have done 2 changes in the settings to make my AAA.exe code 64-bit from 32-bit::
1) [image: 64-bit build]

2) 
[image: 64-bit build for each project in COnfiguration properties page]

Ofcourse the code is compatible for both 32-bit & 64-bit. Are these 2 settings changes in VC2008 complete for making the 32-bit AAA.exe code 64-bit build?

By looking at another stackoverflow link I see there is one more settoing in "Project Configuration properties -> Linker-> Advanced-> Target machine is default to  "not set"
and if I make target machine == "MACHINEx64", I get a different sort of error which I was getting earlier ::

> "fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target
>   machine type 'x64'"

I'm really not having a clarity on if I should be setting the "Target machine" field in linker option as "Not Set" or "MACHINEx64"?

If it's a "YES", I need to figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: what is this `CWTTLogger` class, is it something from one of your libs?

Comment: There can be several things that could be the problem but no reason is visible in what you have shown. Most obvious question is: you are _certain_ you are rebuilding the lib in 64-bit and linking against it and not 32-bit version by accident?

Comment: I have added more details on what all settings I did for changing the 32-bit version to a 64-bit version AAA.EXE. Yes, CWTTLOgger is my class name in the libraries (.lib) I have defined.

Comment: Would like to clarify that my static libraries (.lib) are present in another solution and I have changes all of them to x64. In the snapshot I have shown each project is an indivisual EXE and have no relationship/dependency on another project of the same solution. All my libraries A.lib,B.lib etc... are all present in another solution. –

Answer (score 5):

From the looks of it, you're only changing half of your projects to `x64` and leave the rest to `Win32`. Since you don't show your project's dependencies, its hard to guess if that's a problem or not ... in any case, for compilation to succeed you'll have to switch all of the dependent projects (libs) to x64!

Comment: Would like to clarify that my static libraries (.lib) are present in another solution and I have changes all of them to x64. In the snapshot I have shown each project is an indivisual EXE and have no relationship/dependency on another project of the same solution. All my libraries A.lib,B.lib etc... are all present in another solution.

Comment: Are you also using a platform-specific output directory? e.g. "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\"? Otherwise those could get mixed up from different builds

Comment: Yes I'm using platform specific output directory. I'm not sure, how do i get rid of this error, which has been bothering me from a long time.

Answer (score 4):

That fatal error LNK1112 indicates that you are indeed linking something in 32-bit mode when trying to create a 64-bit executable.

The image 2) shows only *some* but not all projects in 64-bit mode. This sounds like trouble!

Perhaps the problem lies in your LIB directory?
Usually my projects (VS2010 here) differ at:

```
Project Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories
```

which points to `lib32` or `lib64` directory depending on the target architecture.

Comment: Would like to clarify that my static libraries (.lib) are present in another solution and I have changes all of them to x64. In the snapshot I have shown each project is an indivisual EXE and have no relationship/dependency on another project of the same solution. All my libraries A.lib,B.lib etc... are all present in another solution. –

Comment: But you also have 32-bit libraries somewhere right? They are probably under the same name but different path (I see "Logger.lib" name in the error message, not e.g. "Logger32.lib" or "Logger64.lib"). My point is - are you certain that the lib path for 64-bit is set correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Old Thread, I know, but found that I had to add "Explicit" exports to the DEF file to get it to work.  Must be that the 32-bit was implicitly adding, but the 64 was not.   Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what the problem was.

AAA.EXE was using Logger.lib static library which in turn was calling the functions in WTTLog.DLL. And this Microsoft DLL "WTTLog.DLL" is a 32-bit DLL.

That is the reason it wasn't working for me in 64-bit AAA.EXE.

So I did find the answer to the question I raised in this thread i.e how to link 64-bit libraries in a 64-bit application.  BUt still this leaves me with one more question,

"Where do i find the 64-bit version WTTLog.lib and "wttlogger.h" for WTTLog.DLL.
For this I have created a new thread because, the problem is different now.

[How to get the WTTLog.lib and wttlogger.h header file for 64-bit version of WTTLog.DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458663/how-to-get-the-wttlog-lib-and-wttlogger-h-header-file-for-64-bit-version-of-wttl)